# Wilcard in url patterns Yii Framework

Tags: url, yii, pattern-matching

I'm trying to create a dynamic url pattern for the following url:

http://domain.com/content/pagetitle

This is what I have added in the url.rules:

```
'content/<page:.*?>' => 'cms/default/home',
```

this works fine for /`content/pagetitle.html` but not for `/content/pagetitle` while my url suffix is empty. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might also be that the regex "any character" character `.` gets escape *if outside of a named group*.

```
<controller:[a-zA-Z]>/(.*)
```

turns into

```
<controller:[a-zA-Z]>/(\.*)
//                     ^ It escaped it for us even though we didn't want it
```

The solution is simply to make  group for it:

```
<controller:[a-zA-Z]>/<wildcard:.*>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are adding the .*? there...

The following example should work

```
'content/<page:.+>' => 'cms/default/home',
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a wildcard in this case:

```
'content/<page>' => 'cms/default/home',
```